# React Menu / navlinks URL setup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, menu

I try to link my internal pages to a specific section on a one pager website made with React.

Here is my code !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkxb2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERciF.png)

I tryed to read about the react-router but It doesn't make many sens for me im new with React.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

[youtube video](https://youtu.be/Law7wfdg_ls)

I'd recommend actually posting the code instead of pictures of the code